# How many line segments can be drawn that connect the point to the line in 2- space? In 3-space?

Tags: geometry, 3d

Given a line and a point not on the line, determine the following.
How many line segments can be drawn that connect the point to the line in 2- space? In 3-space?

In 2-space I think it would be infinite number of lines. What do you think? I sit the same for 3-space too?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right. There are infinitely (in fact uncountably) many points on the line, and each, together with the point not on the line, determines a different line segment, whether in two or in three dimensions.

Comment: even in 3-space? I thought it might be 0?

Comment: @Donna: I'm not sure I'm following you. What would prevent you from connecting the point not on the line with a point on the line to form a line segment?

Comment: Whenever I get a question about 3-space, it gets me confused and I overthink it. I thought since the answer for 2-space is infinitely many line segments, it could not be the same for 3-space.

Comment: @Donna: More generally, if you have a line and a point not on the line, they define a plane, and in that plane you can do whatever you can do in two-dimensional space.